# How to solve an error in MICE imputation in R - system is computationally singular?

Tags: r, statistics, imputation, r-mice, multiple-mice

I'm trying to impute missing values in my dataset using MICE.
I have a dataset consisting of 116 obs. of 134 variables. My dataset contains numerical, categorical and binary data. All variables with more than 50% missing data have been dropped. I used the quickpred function to select the predictors.
However, I keep getting an error:

```
Error in solve.default(xtx + diag(pen)):
system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.77279e-16
```

This is the code I use

```
inlist <- c("r_age", "r_sex")
exlist <- c("studysubjectid", "studyid") 
pred_matrix <- quickpred(dataset, minpuc = 0.5, include = inlist, exclude = exlist)

imputed_data <- mice(dataset, m = 20, maxit = 20, pred = pred_matrix, printFlag = FALSE, seed=1234)
```

I have tried using different values for mincor and minpuc, however the results do not change.
How can I solve this?